# Staging database version changes in development with RoundhousE

Tags: continuous-integration, roundhouse

EDITED: from original as frankly it was a poor question first time around....

We have a batch script called DEV.DBDeployment.DropCustomCreate.bat, as the name suggests this drops and creates our db from a fresh, a useful tool in Dev but we don't always want to drop the database, sometimes just get the latest changes.

It's worth noting currently every CI checkin triggers a build in TeamCity which pumps the current Major.Minor.BuildNumber.Revision (e.g. 1.0.123.1568) number in to all AssemblyInfo.cs files within all Visual Studio projects.  This obviously allows us to stamp the resultant dll's with the build number, pretty standard stuff for sure. We also overwrite a BuildInfo.txt file in a similar way, most importantly this BuildInfo.txt file is included within every deployment package and sits within the RoundhousE\deployment folder and is referenced by /vf=%version.file% when we run rh.exe as mentioned above from the .bat file.  So we're sorted for deploying to existing databases in Test and Prod.

However in dev the AssemblyVersion is always 0.0.0.0 in AssemblyInfo.cs, as is the version number in BuildInfo.txt, therefore how do devs stage their changes locally against their database.  For example, with this setup when we run rh.exe all changes will be stamped with the version number 0.0.0.0.  Is the expectation that in dev you will *always* drop and create?  If that's the case I'm assuming we need TeamCity to checkin the BuildInfo.txt file so RoundhousE can reference it from source control when executed in dev?

Is there something I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think we discussed this over here - https://github.com/chucknorris/roundhouse/issues/113

Answer (score 0):

As you saying about the .bat file; that is a tool for roundhouse. You have to run that batch file again and again when you want to run your scripts. If you want to run scripts when you build the roundhouse database project then you have to configure that with certain steps. If you wish I can tell you if you replied.